# intuition of hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Forty-four states, Washington D.C., and the Virgin Islands have joined for the Mega Millions lottery game. For this game the player selects five white balls numbered from 1 to 70, inclusive, plus a single gold Mega Ball numbered from 1 to 25, inclusive. There are several different prize options including the following.

(a) What is the probability of matching all five white balls plus the Mega Ball and winning the jackpot?

(b) What is the probability of matching five white balls but not the Mega Ball and winning $1,000,000?

I know this solution involves some hypergeometric distribution. I am quite new to the concept and would like to know what's the intuition to think about it? What distinguishes it from binomial distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What distinguishes it from binomial distribution?

A hypergeometric distributed random variable is a count of successes among a sample of known size drawn ***without*** replacement from a population of known size containing a known amount of successful units.

A binomial distributed random variable is a count of successes among a known amount of *independent* Bernoulli trials with identical success rate.   The counting of successes among draws ***with*** replacement from the above population would be such a random variable.

So here each category is a draw from a set of balls, with a known amount that would match your card, and each ball drawn in each category is *not* replaced.   Thus the count for matches are hypergeometric distributions.

---

The probability for obtaining $k$ from the $K$ possible matches (and $n-k$ from $N-K$ non-matchable balls) when drawing *without* replacement $n$ from $N$ balls is: $$\dfrac{\dbinom Kk\dbinom{N-K}{n-k}}{\dbinom Nn}$$